# How to debug 400 errors when passing JSON to server using Flask

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask

I have read through numerous questions and answers from the community on debugging JQuery 400 errors however I am still struggling to solve them and I am not understanding the cause of this error with JQuery. I have been trying different approaches to pass the "like" status of a post from a user. A previous question was posed in the community for this application and I have adopted that solution however the 400 error persists. I am passing the users "like" or "unlike" status as JSON with the post_id value to Flask. In Flask I storing the "like" status and return jsonify. The HTML and JQuery are as follows:

```
      {% if current_user.has_liked_post(post) %}
        <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm unlike" id="unlike_{{post.id}}">Like <img class="form-img" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='like_icon.png') }}">{{ post.likes_count }}</a>
      {% else %}
        <a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm like" id="like_{{post.id}}">Like <img class="form-img" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='like_icon.png') }}">{{ post.likes_count }}</a>
      {% endif %}

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

      // like and unlike click
      $(".like, .unlike").click(function(){

          var id = this.id;   // Getting Button id
          var split_id = id.split("_");

          var text = split_id[0];
          var post_id = split_id[1];  

          // AJAX Request
          $.ajax({
              url:  "{{ url_for('main.like_post') }}",
              type: 'POST',
              data: JSON.stringify({post_id:post_id, likeunlike:text}),
              dataType: 'json',
              contentType: "application/json",
              success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
      });
    });
    </script>
```

The Flask code:

```
    @main.route("/like_post", methods=["POST", "GET"])
    @login_required
    def like_post():
      post_id = request.json['post_id']
      likeunlike = request.json['likeunlike']
      data = request.json
      post = Post.query.filter_by(id=post.post_id).first_or_404()
      if likeunlike == 'like':
        current_user.like_post(post)
        post.likes_count = Post.likes_count + 1
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
      elif likeunlike == 'unlike':
        current_user.unlike_post(post)
        post.likes_count = Post.likes_count - 1
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
      return jsonify(data)
```

Please explain the mistake so I can prevent this in future. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. A 400 Error is a HTTP Status Code not a JavaScript Error. *A 400 Bad Request error means that the request the client made is incorrect or corrupt, and the server can't understand it.* So the server thinks the request is malformed.

Comment: When you review the Console and the Network tab, what do you see is the Request and Response for the AJAX Post?

Comment: add `if request.method == 'POST':` after the `def like_post():` in your `flask` code

Comment: Thanks for the question @Twisty. I proposed the network response some more and figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer. To debug 400 response when using JQuery, under the network tab in developer tools on Chrome Browser, look at the response preview tab which should provide lots of details on the cause of the 400. In my case the cause was a missing csrf_token from the AJAX post request. To correct this I needed to add the token to the JQuery as follows:

```
    <head>
     <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    </head>

    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
   
     $(".like, .unlike").click(function(){

        // As per the flask documentation, the csrf_token is added to ajax as follows:

            var csrf_token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
            $.ajaxSetup({
                beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                  if (!/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/i.test(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                      xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrf_token);
                   }
                }
            });


      var id = this.id;   // Getting Button id
      var split_id = id.split("_");

      var text = split_id[0];
      var post_id = split_id[1];  

      // AJAX Request
      $.ajax({
          url:  "{{ url_for('main.like_post') }}",
          type: 'POST',
          data: JSON.stringify({post_id:post_id, likeunlike:text}),
          dataType: 'json',
          contentType: "application/json",
          success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

In addition the app needs to be configured to send the csrf_token as follows in **init**.py:

```
    from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect
    csrf = CSRFProtect()

    def create_app(#your config file)
      #other app initializations
      csrf.init_app(app)
```

That resolved the missing token for me.